SLURM slurmd service fails to start on Raspberry Pi 5 cluster due to cgroup.conf parsing errors
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 cluster set up with a master node and a worker node. I successfully installed SLURM on the master node, and I'm currently trying to configure the slurmd daemon to run on the worker node.
Issue
After configuring SLURM, I enabled and started the slurmd service on the master node with the following commands:
sudo systemctl enable slurmd
sudo systemctl start slurmd
sudo systemctl status slurmd

However, the slurmd service fails to start with the following error message:
    × slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-10-26 23:03:46 CEST; 24min ago
     Duration: 5ms
       Docs: man:slurmd(8)
    Process: 2026 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd -D -s $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2026 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 5ms

Oct 26 23:03:46 master systemd[1]: Started slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon.
Oct 26 23:03:46 master slurmd[2026]: slurmd: error: _parse_next_key: Parsing error at unrecognized key: TaskA>
Oct 26 23:03:46 master slurmd[2026]: slurmd: fatal: Could not open/read/parse cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm/cgr>
Oct 26 23:03:46 master slurmd[2026]: error: _parse_next_key: Parsing error at unrecognized key: TaskAffinity
Oct 26 23:03:46 master slurmd[2026]: fatal: Could not open/read/parse cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm/cgroup.conf
Oct 26 23:03:46 master systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 26 23:03:46 master systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

My current cgroup.conf is as follows:
CgroupMountpoint="/sys/fs/cgroup"
CgroupAutomount=yes
CgroupReleaseAgentDir="/etc/slurm/cgroup"
AllowedDevicesFile="/etc/slurm/cgroup_allowed_devices_file.conf"
ConstrainCores=no
TaskAffinity=yes
ConstrainRAMSpace=yes
ConstrainSwapSpace=no
ConstrainDevices=no
AllowedRamSpace=100
AllowedSwapSpace=0
MaxRAMPercent=100
MaxSwapPercent=100
MinRAMSpace=30

Questions
How do I correct the errors in cgroup.conf that lead to the parsing errors mentioned in the logs?
Are there specific configurations required for SLURM to work correctly with Raspberry Pi 5 and its architecture?
What are the common causes for the high latency error reported in SLURM, and how can I address them?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Verified that Munge is functioning correctly:
ssh pi@node01 munge -n

Checked the status of the slurmctld service on the master node, which is also reported as down.
Investigated the cgroup.conf for parsing errors.


The error message is self-explanatory:

error: _parse_next_key: Parsing error at unrecognized key: TaskAffinity

That is not a valid configuration option for that file. See the list of valid options in the documentation for the cgroup configuration file.
It was removed in Slurm version 21.08.2 and replaced with
TaskPlugin=cgroup,affinity"

in slurm.conf.
